# How do I use a font package but keep math font unchanged?

Tags: fonts, pdftex, computer-modern

I am using two font packages: `fourier` (which is in fact Utopia) for overall text and `chivo` for sans-serif.

However, I don't like the changes these packages make to math font. I tried to revert math back to Computer Modern with the following commands:

```
% Revert mathcal back to `cms` -- it works
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathcal}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}

% Attempt to revert all math back to `cms`: does not work
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathsf}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
```

I also tried replacing `\mathsf` with `\mathnormal` and `\mathroman` to no avail.

Here's my minimal reproducible example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[scale=0.9]{Chivo}

% Fix \mathcal but no success changing overall math font
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathcal}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathsf}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}

\begin{document}
Math calligraphy looks ok, but arrows are ugly: 
$$P \rightarrow \mathcal{O}(n^2) \wedge \leftrightarrow 8$$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Compiter Modern for maths and utopia don't match well. You shouldn't do that.

Comment: What should I use instead?

Comment: @Bernard To anser the question you made in the answer below, I don't like math caligraphy and operators: brackets and arrows are short, and `\vee` doesn't stand out too much from the letter `v`.

Comment: Did you try `mathdesign` with option `utopia`? (it laso defines  maths packages for Bitstream Charter and URW Garamond).

Comment: That's a good suggestion, but it breaks my attempt to change `\mathcal`. Could you also suggest a way to fix that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is better to avoid that fourier change the math, so don't load the package but change only the font family:

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{futs}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.9]{Chivo}


\begin{document}

abc \sffamily abc

\end{document}
```

Comment: Then you didn't use my example, I'm switching to T1-encoding.

Comment: What is the problem with fourier maths fonts?