# Attempting to use different fonts in PDFLaTeX (Baskervaldx and New PX)

Tags: fonts, pdftex

I use `newpxtext`, but for **italics** I want to use those from `Baskervaldx`. The following code (borrowed from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/509120/32352) answer) does this for the `Chivo` font as default and **roman** fonts from the `fourier` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{futs}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{Chivo}
\begin{document}
\textrm{abc} (roman \texttt{fourier})

\textsf{abc} (sans \texttt{Chivo})
\end{document}
```

[image]

To see that this indeed works, compare the output above with the output from the code that leaves **roman** fonts untouched. Since `Chivo` only deals with sans serif fonts, **roman** fonts come from `cm` in this case:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{Chivo}
\begin{document}
\textrm{abc} (roman \texttt{Computer Modern})

\textsf{abc} (sans \texttt{Chivo})
\end{document}
```

[image]

Now, when I replace `Chivo` with `newpxtext` and `fourier` with `Baskervaldx` (and redefine italics instead of roman), something goes wrong:

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\itdefault}{Baskervaldx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newpxtext}
\begin{document}
\textrm{abc} (roman \texttt{New PX})

\textit{abc} (italic \texttt{Baskervaldx}, supposedly)
\end{document}
```

[image]

I am aware that specifying fonts attributes is a lot easier within LuaLaTeX (by using `fontspec`), but I need to be able to do this in PDFLaTeX.

Answer (score 1):

The `\itdefault` command does not define a font family used only for italics, but the shape parameter (e.g. `it` or `sl`).  Also, `Baskervaldx` is not a font family, but `Baskervaldx-LF` is.

If you really, truly want to do this, in PDFTeX and not a Unicode engine, here is how:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newpxmath}

% Kitbashing together from t1zpllf.fd and t1baskervaldx-LF.fd

\makeatletter
\global\let\zpl@scaled\@empty
\gdef\zpl@lsfx{}

\DeclareFontFamily{T1}{weirdtext}{\zpl@scaled}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{weirdtext}{b}{sc}{<-> \zpl@scaled zpl-Bold-lf-sc\zpl@lsfx-t1}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{weirdtext}{b}{n}{<-> \zpl@scaled zpl-Bold-lf-t1}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{weirdtext}{b}{scit}{<-> \zpl@scaled zpl-BoldItalic-lf-sc\zpl@lsfx-t1}{}
% \DeclareFontShape{T1}{weirdtext}{b}{it}{<-> \zpl@scaled zpl-BoldItalic-lf-t1}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{weirdtext}{m}{sc}{<-> \zpl@scaled zpl-Regular-lf-sc\zpl@lsfx-t1}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{weirdtext}{m}{n}{<-> \zpl@scaled zpl-Regular-lf-t1}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{weirdtext}{m}{scit}{<-> \zpl@scaled zpl-Italic-lf-sc\zpl@lsfx-t1}{}
% \DeclareFontShape{T1}{weirdtext}{m}{it}{<-> \zpl@scaled zpl-Italic-lf-t1}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{weirdtext}{bx}{sc}{<->ssub * zplLF/b/sc}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{weirdtext}{bx}{n}{<->ssub * zplLF/b/n}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{weirdtext}{bx}{scit}{<->ssub * zplLF/b/scit}{}
% \DeclareFontShape{T1}{weirdtext}{bx}{it}{<->ssub * zplLF/b/it}{}
% point to real slanted fonts
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{weirdtext}{m}{sl}{<-> \zpl@scaled zpl-Slanted-lf-t1}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{weirdtext}{b}{sl}{<-> \zpl@scaled zpl-BoldSlanted-lf-t1}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{weirdtext}{bx}{sl}{<->ssub * zplLF/b/sl}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{weirdtext}{b}{scsl}{<->ssub * zplLF/b/scit}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{weirdtext}{m}{scsl}{<->ssub * zplLF/m/scit}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{weirdtext}{b}{scsl}{<->ssub * zplLF/b/scit}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{weirdtext}{bx}{it}{
      <-> ssub * weirdtext/b/it
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{weirdtext}{b}{it}{
      <-> Baskervaldx-BolIta-lf-t1
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{weirdtext}{m}{it}{
      <-> Baskervaldx-Ita-lf-t1
}{}
\makeatother

\renewcommand\familydefault{weirdtext}

\begin{document}
\textrm{abc} (roman \texttt{New PX})

\textit{abc} (italic \texttt{Baskervaldx})
\end{document}
```

This will not change your variables in math mode.  You might addiitonally want `mathastext` for that.

Comment: I don't really, truly **want** to do this, but I **must** do (arXiv only accepts PDFTeX-made documents). For the math fonts I intend to use `eulerpx`: I omitted this in the question because I considered it not relevant. I see that you invokes `newpxmath` instead of `newpxtext`, so I am not sure whether your solution indeed works for my specific problem. However, you went to such lengths to solve my problem, so thank you very much anyway.

Comment: @MatemáticosChibchas This should work with `eulerpx`. If you have further questions, please post and let me know?